# Determine thread status with join and InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading

Seems to be that this method is takes in an array of threads, then determines if they have completed using InterruptedException, which seems plausible to me.

```
private static void waitUntilAllThreadsFinished(Thread[] threadArr) {
    for(int i=0; i<threadArr.length; i++) {
        try {
            threadArr[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        log.debug("thread ["+threadArr[i].getName()+"] have completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: InterruptedException is thrown when the current thread operation (here it's `join`) has been interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if the `thread` has been interrupted , the use `public boolean isInterrupted()` method on the `thread` reference. This code is trying to block the current thread on each of the thread's completion, and retrying if it got interrupted in th meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`getState`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29) is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I would not force the throw and catch, since it is not free of cost. The Thread class have methods to access the current state of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not just determine whether all threads have completed, but **waits** for all of them to complete. And it's not using InterruptedException to do this. If join() calls on finished (dead) thread, the code just continues on without exception.
But it will work, I guess...